# How to parse image URL from json

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing

```
"weatherIconUrl": [
{
"value": "http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png"
}
],
```

this is my json data i can able to fetch data in text type but i can't able to fetch image url from weatherIconUrl array

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. Are you asking how to get the url out of the JSON or how to get the image from the url?

Comment: U want to show the image from JSon url

Comment: yes i want to show image

Answer (score 2):

Use following code of line for get value of key `@"value"`

```
NSString * imgURLString = [[[myMaindictonary objectForKey:@"weatherIconUrl"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"value"];
```

And convert this string to URL

```
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[imgURLString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

And you can also get image from this URL by

```
UIImage *myImg = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:myURL]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Its quite easy,

```
 NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;

 NSArray *weatherArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:yourResponseData options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];

 NSLog(@"weatherArray : %@", weatherArray);

 NSString *weatherIconImageURL = [[weatherArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"weatherIconUrl"]];

 NSLog(@"weatherIconImageURL : %@", weatherIconImageURL);
```